# How to rotate multiple faces in the same direction

Tags: modeling

I'd like to know how to select multiple faces and rotate them along the z-axis (or along any other axis) in the same direction? I know this may be a pretty simple question and has been answered somewhere, but I just don't know what to google.

Of course you could rotate every single face individually, but that would be really time consuming. The effect I'm looking for is something like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: do you know how to set the rotation pivot to `individual origin`, also  i don't get how those two face have rotated the in the same direction to end up like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Change pivot point to Individual Origins and rotate on Z axis, or instead of rotate you can Shear the faces from top view, with Median Point Pivot using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and drag the mouse until you get the angle that you need.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and ended up with something like in the first picture above (on the left), and that isn't what I'm looking for. To be more specific,
I'm trying to rotate the faces away from each other. In this respect the title may be little misleading (it depends how you look at it).

Comment: Yes the text confused me a bit. In this case I don't see one button solution. But you can do that on multiple faces for each side.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is my input.
First select all the faces you want to rotate by holding down the Shift key and clicking on them.
Next you want to press the 'R' key for Rotate and than the 'Z' key to constrain the rotation to the Z axis (or 'X' or 'Y').
Next, type in the angle you want to rotate them (i.e. 15, 30, 45, etc).

You could also just select all the faces you want rotated to a specific angle and change their rotation value in the properties panel.

Hope this helps.  Will check back in.